# EnumResourceNames returns Windows error 998 (Invalid access to memory location)

Tags: delphi, dll

(see edits at bottom)

Using EnumResourceNames, I am trying to find icons stored as resources in my own dll. Here is the entire dll code:

```
library focusRes;

{$R focusResResource.res} // contains the icons I need to load
{$R *.res}

begin
end.
```

I can load the dll correctly using LoadLibrary and LoadLibraryEx (verified). But a call to EnumResourceNames returns false, and GetLastError returns 998 (Invalid access to memory location). The calling code is:

```
hdll := LoadLibraryEx( PChar( DLLFilename ), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE );
// OR: hdll := LoadLibrary( PChar( DLLFilename ));
enumResult := EnumResourceNames( hDll, RT_ICON, @EnumResFlags, 0 );
// (hDll is the handle returned from LoadLibrary)
```

and the callback function:

```
function EnumResFlags( hDll : HMODULE; ResType, ResName : PChar; 
   notUsed : pointer ) : integer; stdcall;
begin
  // NEVER GETS CALLED
  // log( ResName);
  result := 1; // continue enumeration
end;
```

The callback is a standalone function (not an object method or a local function).

In my investigation I have found some confusing clues:

- The problem seems to be with my dll, because if I substitute a random
  dll from a third-party application, the problem goes away.
- The problem seems **not** to be with my dll, because I can open it
  in a third-party icon editor, and all the icons stored in the dll are
  loaded correctly.
- When I try to create a resourcestream for a specific icon name, the
  exception is "Resource [name] not found". (But the icon editor finds it fine)

**(Delphi XE on Windows 7 32-bit)**

**EDIT 1:** Create a new Delphi project and put the following line in it:

```
enumResult := EnumResourceNames( hInstance, RT_ICON, @EnumCallback, 0 );
```

Result: error 998. Change RT_ICON to something else, like RT_RTCDATA, and the problem goes away.

**EDIT 2:** The problem **does not occur** if I do not reference the ResName parameter in the callback. (If I only say "result := 1" in the callback, no error.) Went back to Delphi 3 (!) and got the same exact result, so it is not particular to XE. And if I try to enum RT_RCDATA instead of RT_ICON, no problem wither and I **can** read ResName.

Comment: Also found: if, as an experiment, I substitude hInstance for the dll module handle, the result is the same: error 998. (So the problem is not with how the dll is loaded).

Comment: ...and if I pass zero as the callback function address, the error is still 998.

Comment: Is your DLL already being loaded by your application in some way?

Comment: No. It is loaded directly before the Enum call.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the content of your resource script, and the attempt you make to "create a resourcestream" including the actual code that relates to that sample of the resource script?

Comment: Are you by chance loading a 32bit DLL into a 64bit process, or vice versa?

Comment: Found something else, perhaps I should rephrase my question now. 

The problem does NOT occur as long as I do not try to reference the 'ResName' parameter in the callback function. The problem only occurs when I do, such as "showmessage( ResName )". Stepping through code, the ResType and ResName params appear empoty (but that's still not the reason for the error).

Comment: @KenWhite The rc file has sixty lines like these:

flag_add ICON "..\\res\\flags\\add.ico"
flag_arrow_down ICON "..\\res\\flags\\arrow down.ico"

(THe icons are from a commercial set, with multiple sizes and color depths)

I compile it with brcc32 into the res file, which gets linked to the dll.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, this is all happening on my 32-bit Win 7.

Comment: I have SOLVED the problem temporarily, by changing the rc file to store icons as RCDATA instead. Now all the code posted in my question is running fine, and all the names are properly returned. But, this is a stop-gap measure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not correctly resolving the `lpszType` and `lpszName` parameters of the callback. Your failing test involves resource IDs being passed to your callback, not resource names.  When you try to access the first 64kb of your process memory via a pointer, it is an invalid memory access.

You need to test if `ResType`/`ResName` is a name or ID and then treat it accordingly, like so:

```
function EnumResFlags( hDll : HMODULE; ResType, ResName : PChar; notUsed : pointer ) : integer; stdcall;
begin
  if IS_INTRESOURCE(ResName) then
    log(IntToStr(Integer(ResName)))
  else
    log(ResName);
  ...
end;
```

If your Delphi version does not have `IS_INTRESOURCE()` defined, you can define it manually:

```
function IS_INTRESOURCE(lpszType: PChar): BOOL;
begin
  Result := ULONG_PTR(lpszType) shr 16 = 0;
end;
```

Comment: Use `if IS_INTRESOURCE(lpszName) then` instead of `if (Integer(lpszName) shr 16) = 0 then`. `IS_INTRESOURCE()` is in Delphi's `Windows` unit.

Comment: @Remy - I can't find IS_INTRESOURCE in D2007. Obviously later versions have it. Thanks!

Comment: I just checked, it was added in XE2.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't understand how any of the icons stored in the dll could be using an ID instead of a name, until I realized Delphi compiler automatically inserts its own "Main Icon". It is probably that icon which was passed to the callback and triggered the problem.

Comment: @mood - You're welcome.   Yes, it seems plausible. AFAICS, Delphi's default 'MAINICON' icon group is composed of one unnamed icon.